# Could not load assembly in Windows Server 2003 in program built with Windows 8.1/Visual Studio 2013

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio

I have a program that works on my development PC but not on the server I want to run it on. When I run the program on the server I get this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo,
>   Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

My development PC is Windows 8.1 with Visual Studio 2013 and SQL Server 2012 developer tools. The server is Windows Server 2003 R2, Standard Edition, Service Pack 2 running .NET 4.

I first tried to set Copy Local to true for each assembly that the server couldn't find. Then I finally got an error for an assembly I did't explicitly reference in my program so I figured I might be going about this in the wrong way.

> Message: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrProvider, Version=11.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. StackTrace:
>   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.CallerHavePermissionToUseSQLCLR()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager..ctor(SqlConnection
>   sqlConnectionObject)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection..ctor(SqlConnection
>   sqlConnection)

The assemblies I'm using in my program can be installed from [Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Feature Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065) but these 2012 packages are not compatible with Windows Server 2003. The latest assemblies I managed to get installed on Win Server 2003 were from [Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Feature Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16978), which gets me up to Version 10 of the assemblies on the server. When I try to install these on my Windows 8.1 development PC, I get this error:

> Installation of Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects failed
>   because a higher version already exists on the machine. To proceed,
>   uninstall the higher version and then run Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2
>   Management Objects Setup again.

I don't like the idea of going backwards from 2012 to 2008 assemblies on my dev machine, I have to support both SQL Server 2005 and 2012. Is there some way I can tell Visual Studio 2013 to target these older assembly versions?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the assembly version was what I needed to do. You can specify a different assembly version in Visual Studio by creating an app.config file and adding something like the following:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo"
                          publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="11.0.0.0"
                         newVersion="10.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```